# C language, readdir and segmentation fault on running

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, readdir, opendir, dirent.h

This code give back a segmentatin fault when I try to run it
Nothing appears wihle building the file with gcc

If you have any Idea about where to search to fix it give your advise thanks.

necessarly its in the function readrep() that must happen,especialy with opendir() and readdir()   but I don't see something wrong,
thanks to help

```
#include<dirent.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 256


FILE* f;

void gowrite(char * chemin){
  f=fopen("locate.db.tmp","a+");

 int size=strlen(chemin);
    char str[MAX];

    fwrite(&size,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(str,sizeof(char),size,f);
    fclose(f);
}
void readRep(char* str){
  struct dirent repStruct;
  struct dirent * prepStruct;
  struct stat structStat;
  struct stat *buff;
  buff=&structStat;
  prepStruct=&repStruct;
DIR * d=opendir(str);

  while((prepStruct=readdir(d))!=NULL){

  int x;
  char* fi=malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
  fi=(prepStruct->d_name);
  x=stat(fi,buff);
  mode_t m;
  m=structStat.st_mode;
 int test;
 test=S_ISREG(m);

 if(test==0){

strcat(str,"/");
 strcat(str,fi);
 readRep(str);
 }
 else{
 char *chemin=realpath(fi,NULL); 
gowrite(chemin);
 free(chemin);
 chemin=NULL;
 }

 }


}

int main(int argN,char** argv){






  char* path=getenv("HOME");  
  chdir(path);

  readRep(".");









rename("locate.db.tmp","locate.db");
exit(0);





}
```

If you may help me thanks

Comment: Compile with symbols (option `-g`), then run the code using a debugger (gdb). It'll show the exact location where the crash occurs and allows ou to inspect all variables used.

Comment: Also properly formatting sources whould surely raise acceptance to read them.

Comment: ALWAYS check the result of fopen().

Answer (score 3):

It may not be the only problem, but you are passing to `readRep` function the string literal `"."` and then within this function you use `strcat` to append something to it. You cannot modify string literals, and for sure you cannot append anything to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
void gowrite(char * chemin){
  f=fopen("locate.db.tmp","a+");
  int size=strlen(chemin);
  char str[MAX];

  fwrite(&size,sizeof(int),1,f);
  fwrite(str,sizeof(char),size,f);
  fclose(f);
```

"chemin"/"size" and "str"/"MAX" do have nothing in common, not even the sizes. But you use one to output the other. *ugly*

btw: you do not initialize "str", so it may contain garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found ,
 the readdir() function read all the current direcory and subdirectory,...
(I thought it only read the current directory)

So when I make the recursive call upon my function readRep() ,that's not clear but that's may go at to much complexity to be handle .